# htaccess url rewriting does not work the way i expect it to work

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

i know this question is asked like a million times, but i can't seem to get it to work.

what i want is when i type the url `localhost:8080/contact` that it loads the `localhost:8080/sample/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3` page.

i have tried the following:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} contact
 RewriteRule ^^([-\w\.])$ sample/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3 [NC,L]`

but now when i do `localhost:8080/contact` i see the WAMP server homepage instead of the contact page.

also tried this:
`RewriteRule   ^contact/?$   sample/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3  [NC,L]`

but that gives errors for some reason.

rewrite engine is on: `RewriteEngine On` and
apache rewrite module is on.

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever covers all of this (and if you've already worked through that, you should demonstrate it). An obvious issue with the rule is that the pattern you're matching REQUEST_URI against should start with a `/` - so `/contact` rather than `contact`.

Comment: There is no anchor, so a pattern of `contact` will still match. Of course  that might still be wrong, but it *will* match. One other problem is `^^` at the start. Without testing myself I've no idea if that will do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, after trying all the possibilities this is what worked:

```
RewriteRule contact/?    /sample/index.php?id=3   [L,NC]
```

No conditions seem to work perfectly.